# Adding border dynamically shifts the elements

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am creating a grid of squares, which look like this:
[image]

I have added the functionality, that whenever I click a certain box,it will be highlighted. So I dynamically add a class, which will add the border functionality to the selected box.However, my boxes shifts towards right, as can bee seen (when I click any box).

[image]

Why is it so?
Below are my css code and directive code.

```
 body { padding-top:30px; }

.square {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom : 10%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin:1.66%;
    /*background-color:#1E1E1E;*/
    background-color:RED;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    height:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 5%;

}

.higlight {
  border-width: small;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: black;
  /*border-color: #0001fe;*/
};
```

Template for my directive is as follows:

```
template : '<div class="square" ng-class="{higlight: $id === active}" ng-style="{{data.color}}" ng-click="active = $id" ng-transclude> <div class="content"> </div>  </div>'
```

How can I modify my css or template, that my boxes do not shift to right side.

Comment: Add  `box-sizing: content-box;` to your boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your `float:left` *when you're adding a margin*, its *affecting the containers around it* and changing the float style. 
You can make use of `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` on the **square class** and it will work fine.

```css
body { padding-top:30px; }

.square {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom : 10%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin:1.66%;
    /*background-color:#1E1E1E;*/
    background-color:RED;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    height:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 5%;

}

.square:hover {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: black;
  margin-top:-2px;
  /*border-color: #0001fe;*/
};
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is still a small issue, the whole line of boxes shifts down, when I hover over it. How can I avoid this? Thanks in advance. Although I tried using ´box-sizing: border-box;´, but still it does not resolved the issue.

Comment: I think the most easy solution and clean would be adding a negative margin, I updated it.